# Special cookies to login by WebRequest method in C#

Tags: c#, cookies, webrequest

I try this code to get a cookie from a website

```
CookieCollection cookies = new CookieCollection();
CookieContainer cooki = new CookieContainer();
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create(weburl.Text);
request.CookieContainer = cooki;
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
StreamReader read = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream());
request.CookieContainer = cooki;
request.CookieContainer.Add(cookies);
cookies = response.Cookies;

if(response.Cookies != null &&  response.Cookies.Count != 0)
{
    foreach(Cookie c in response.Cookies)
        listBox2.Items.Add(c.ToString());

}
else
        listBox2.Items.Add("No Cookies");
```

But when i try this for a website like http://www.cloob.com nothing happens.

I try this site by webbrowser in C# and tried this code

```
string cooki = webbrowser1.Document.Cookie.tostring();
```

and I got a lot of information like this:

> Cookie=LMOT=1343810524; IdM=no;
>   __utma=204761026.19745671.1343776441.1343805546.1343810526.4; __utmz=204761026.1343776441.1.1.utmccn=(direct)|utmcsr=(direct)|utmcmd=(none); CR=%7B%22online_count%22:%5B%7B%22count%22:8059,%22status%22:%22available%22%7D,%7B%22count%22:%221204%22,%22status%22:%22invisible%22%7D,%7B%22count%22:%2276%22,%22status%22:%22busy%22%7D%5D%7D;
>   m_id=1343781310_7982757; LCCT=1343809271; __utmb=204761026;
>   __utmc=204761026

Now how can I get this by webrequest?

Answer (score 0):

While your code is a little redundant redundant I don't see anything wrong with it. It works for me when I tested it against `http://www.google.com/`. `http://www.cloob.com` might possibly be setting cookies in javascript, which would explain why you can see the cookies in a `WebBrowser` object but not with a `WebRequest`.

Comment: yes it works for http://www.google.com/ or http://www.facebook.com i just want to login a website and need to got cookies first